# Error ResolvePromise [Object Object]

Tags: angular

Hola estoy intentando hacer una subida de archivos pero me tira el error al entrar en la página vaya no hago ni el intento de subir.

Mi servicio:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
import { GLOBAL } from './global';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class UploadService{
    public url:string;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient){
        this.url=GLOBAL.url;
    }

    public postFileImagen(imagenParaSubir: File){
        const formData = new FormData(); 
        formData.append('imagenPropia', imagenParaSubir, imagenParaSubir.name); 
        return this.http.post(this.url+'upload', formData);
    }
}
```

También os dejo mi componente, si quito `_enviadoImagen` si que me funciona la página pero claro... ya no funciona el servicio.

```
import { UploadService } from '../../services/upload.service';
export class DocumentosComponent implements OnInit {
      //Subida de archivos
      public respuestaImagenEnviada:any;
      public resultadoCarga:any;

      constructor(private _enviandoImagen:UploadService) {}

      public cargandoImagen(files: FileList){
            this._enviandoImagen.postFileImagen(files[0]).subscribe(
                response => {
                    this.respuestaImagenEnviada = response; 
                    if(this.respuestaImagenEnviada <= 1){
                        console.log("Error en el servidor"); 
                    }else{
                        if(this.respuestaImagenEnviada.code == 200 && this.respuestaImagenEnviada.status == "success"){
                            this.resultadoCarga = 1;
                        }else{
                            this.resultadoCarga = 2;
                        }
                    }
                },
                error => {
                    console.log(<any>error);
                }
            );//FIN DE METODO SUBSCRIBE
        }
    }
```

El php no lo pongo por que por ahora no se si me funciona o no debido a que no puedo probarlo.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner todo el stacktrace del error? No veo nada que sea evidentemente erróneo en tu código

Comment: el error que te podria estar pasando es que no veo que envias los datos de session en el header